# Page file problem

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I installed Windows on my new SSD and for about a day I had a HDD connected to the computer. I moved the page file to the HDD, but at some point I decided to ditch the HDD altogether and put it in my server.

However since I forgot to remove the page file from the HDD, every time I start Windows 7 it gives me an error that it was unable to create a page file on the preconfigured HDD, so it will automatically adjust it itself.

Is there a registry key or something else I can edit so that it stops trying to make a page file on a non-connected HDD?

Comment: Have you tried changing the location of it back to the SSD in system properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the location back to the SSD drive using Windows 7's Performance Options.

1. Hit **Windows** + **Pause Break** keys
2. In the left pane, click on **Advanced system settings**
3. Click on the **Advanced** tab
4. Click on the **Settings...** button in the **Performance** section
5. Click on the **Advanced** tab
6. Click on the **Change...** button
7. Highlight the drive you want to work with

It's recommended that your page file size equal your RAM size.

Comment: Well I don't want a page file since I have enough RAM and I only use the PC for gaming. But that kind of worked. I set the page file back to the SSD drive, restarted and removed the page file and now no error pops up. Thanks.

Comment: @xciter: I've heard that not having a Page file in Windows 7 causes issues.  I prefer to leave it alone.  I'll give you this link that talks about why you shouldn't disable the Page file.  http://lifehacker.com/5426041/understanding-the-windows-pagefile-and-why-you-shouldnt-disable-it